# while loop in c does not end

Tags: c, while-loop

When I run this code, it enters an indefinite loop. Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char x;                
    x=0;
    while(x<=225)
    {
        printf("%c=%d\n",x,x);
        x=x+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `char` is probably `signed` in your implementation so `x` has the range `-128` to `127`.

Comment: write `unsigned char`

Comment: oh.. misread 225 as 255...

Comment: @EugeneSh. me too.  Who wouldn't?  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char` then the valid range of values is `[-128, 127]`.
It is undefined behavior when after increment the result value exceeds 127.

Instead of the type `char` you can use the type `unsigned char`.